# MQL4 - how to do simple math?

Tags: math, line, division, mql4

I have a stupid question. Why this is working:

```
double price = 0.2;
ObjectCreate("line",OBJ_HLINE,0,0, price);
```

but something like that is not:

```
double price = 2/10;
ObjectCreate("line",OBJ_HLINE,0,0, price);
```

or

```
double tmp = 2;
double price = tmp / 10;
ObjectCreate("line",OBJ_HLINE,0,0, price);
```

? Is there a special trick for dividing two numbers? :) 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have not to change your variable type before using it (Casting) unless you intend to do so.

To keep your code above working properly you have to write your numbers as follows:

```
double price = 2.0/10.0;
  ObjectCreate("line",OBJ_HLINE,0,0, price);
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it was problem of typecasting. More here:
http://docs.mql4.com/basis/types/casting.